# How to resolve Function RunTime Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am getting a runtime error when calling my function from a SubRoutine. The highlighted line is `Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(x, c))`.

The generated error is `RunTime Error 1004 Application - defined or object - defined error`

**CODE**

```
Private LastRow As Long
Private wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Private ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("clientmenu")
Private CellRow As Integer    ' create a variable to hold the cell row
LastRow = Sheet3.Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
CellRow = ActiveCell.Row

Private x As Long, c As Long, s As Long
Const CONTACT_START As Long = 13 ' Column E
Const COL_PER_CONTACT As Long = 2 ' Columns per Contact
Const CONTACT_DROPS As Long = 14 'Column G
Const COL_PER_DROPS As Long = 2 'Columns per Contact


s = CONTACT_START
c = CONTACT_START
x = Me.lblRow
Z = LastRow

Public Function callDate() As Date
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("clientmenu")
        ' Look for first empty one
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(x, c))
            c = c + COL_PER_CONTACT
        Loop
        .Cells(x, c) = addnewClient.contact.value
        '.Cells(x, c + 1) = Me.cdates1.Value
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ```LastColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=ActiveSheet.Cells(x, c), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).column``` gets the last column and saves you a loop

Comment: `x = CLng(Me.lblRow.Caption)` or something along those lines

Comment: @TimWilliams `RunTime Error 1004 Application - defined or object - defined error` Unfortunately your suggestion did not resolve the error.

Comment: What's the value of x and c when it fails?

Comment: @TimWilliams values on fail; `x=empty` & `c=empty`

Comment: @Jose, isn't that the wrong use of `IsEmpty`? the cells are not variables that need to be initialised. What are you trying to achieve? If x and c are empty, then you will get a runtime error because you are trying to access a non-existent cell, which is an object defined error. If you state the purpose of the code or that line, then a solution can be prescribed

Comment: @AAA `IsEmpty` works with any `Variant`. A cell's value will be `Variant/Empty` when the cell has no content and no formula. No `Long` can ever be `Empty` though, so I dispute OP's claim that `x=empty` and `c=empty`, that's downright impossible. EDIT: Nevermind, I missed that we were looking at two separate scopes. OP is missing `Option Explicit`, `c` and `x` are undeclared/out-of-scope variables

Comment: The problem is the two variables are themselves empty. .Cell(x,y) is 1 to x based so it would make sense youre getting an 1004 error

Comment: Or Mathieu could be more correct here, I was just commenting on what I saw/know about the function

Comment: @DougCoats no, you're right, the variables are indeed `Empty`, because they're undeclared `Variant`s. Part of the problem is that the OP's code makes no sense whatsoever, `c` and `x` and others are being assigned outside of a procedure scope, so as presented, that code can't even compile, let alone produce a run-time error.

Comment: @DougCoats the variables are not empty, i am declaring their value. Please see code

Comment: @MathieuGuindon i am hovering over the error line, which then reads  my variables are empty

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, then try to compile. `callDate` has no knowledge of any of the variables it's using, and that's why they're all `Empty`.

Comment: @Jose which is it dude? theyre either empty or theyre not. It sounds like theyre empty hence Im correct.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for making me realize the obvious. I rewrote my code after your suggestion. Posting answer below

Comment: @DougCoats i never said they weren't empty, I said they are being declared

Comment: "the variables are not empty, i am declaring their value. Please see code – Jose 25 mins ago" - just sayin' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

By moving the variables inside of the function i was able to get the expected results with no runtime error.

```
Private LastRow As Long
Private CellRow As Integer    ' create a variable to hold the cell row
Private x As Long, c As Long, s As Long, z As Long
Const CONTACT_START As Long = 13 ' Column E
Const COL_PER_CONTACT As Long = 2 ' Columns per Contact
Const CONTACT_DROPS As Long = 14 'Column G
Const COL_PER_DROPS As Long = 2 'Columns per Contact





Public Function callDate() As Date
s = CONTACT_START
c = CONTACT_START
x = CLng(addnewClient.lblRow.Caption)
z = LastRow
LastRow = Sheet3.Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
CellRow = ActiveCell.Row
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("clientmenu")
        c = CONTACT_START
        x = CLng(addnewClient.lblRow.Caption)
        ' Look for first empty one
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(x, c))
            c = c + COL_PER_CONTACT
        Loop
        .Cells(x, c) = addnewClient.contact.value
        '.Cells(x, c + 1) = Me.cdates1.Value
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: `CellRow` should be a `Long` - otherwise you can expect an overflow error (6) when its value is >32,767 - i.e. `2 ^ 15 - 1`; `Integer` is a 16-bit integer type, while the maximum value of a `Long` is `2 ^ 31 - 1` (32-bit integer), which will accept any possible value for a row number on a worksheet. Also I'd suggest moving the declarations into the `callDate` scope, since their meaning only makes sense inside that function. Keep variables' scopes as tight as possible, you'll avoid many problems that way. And `Option Explicit` at the top, always. Cheers!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon valuable feedback as always!